# Apple Help Book tutorial

Tags: macos, cocoa, apple-help

Can somebody point me to an up to date tutorial on how to create a help book for Cocoa application. Everything I've found online is old and outdated and the Apple documentation doesn't make it any clearer. One specific thing I can't figure out is how to create a .help bundle.

Comment: I would just like to comment that trying to create even a very simple help book for a Cocoa app always is an exercise in extreme frustration for me. I have a terrible time getting the Help Indexer to work and/or getting it to appear when selecting from the help menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking this question I went to the bookstore and got this book. It has a very good step by step tutorial on how to create the help book. It has answered all my questions.

http://www.peachpit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321670418

Answer (score 12):

This document contains information on the help bundle layout (and Apple Help in general):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-TPXREF104

On the other hand, the help bundle format has never really been required (and in some OS versions was not officially supported despite Apple using it themselves for years).

All I do is set `CFBundleHelpBookFolder` and `CFBundleHelpBookName` (in `Info.plist`).  The latter is a human-readable title, e.g. "YourApp Help", that must match the `AppleTitle` in the HTML.

I set `CFBundleHelpBookFolder` to simply the name "Help" and I create the folder `Something.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Help` in the application bundle.  In this directory I place `index.html` (containing the required `<meta>` tags `AppleTitle` and `AppleIcon`) and `ExactMatch.plist`.  (By the way, it is actually a good idea if *everything else* goes into a subfolder below this point so that the help system doesn't have to search many top-level files.)